# TestNG running JUnit tests but not reporting all results

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, testng

**Background:**
I have a a series of 172 integration tests that have been written using JUnit. Since our project needed to have them run on an embedded arm chip the tests have to be compiled into a jar and run using the command line. We realized after writing the tests that JUnit did not support xml output as part of the default library (which we required for jenkins). We added TestNG to our project because it provided a simple way to output XML results for our JUnit tests.

We are using the following command to run our tests:
`/usr/local/frc/JRE/bin/java -ea -jar wpilibJavaIntegrationTests-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -junit -testclass edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.test.TestSuite`

Where TestSuite is a bit like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    WpiLibJTestSuite.class,
    CANTestSuite.class,
    CommandTestSuite.class,
    SmartDashboardTestSuite.class
})
public class TestSuite{
    static{
        //Some basic java.util.logging setup stuff
    }
}
```

Each suite listed has its own set of test classes listed in a similarly formatted class.

**Problem:**
All 172 tests are being run by TestNG however it is only reporting 81 tests run and not reporting some failures (there were really two tests that failed but only one was reported).

```
===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 81, Failures: 1, Skips: 8
===============================================
```

It seems that that unreported tests are the ones `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`
Is there any way to get TestNG to properly recognize these tests and report their results appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change it to the TestNG way of doing it. (You should probably scan your code for imports from junit and replace them with corresponding TestNG constructs.)

This can be easily done, as most of the assertion statements are nearly identical to the JUnit ones (in fact several frameworks exist for automatically converting all tests to TestNG), and the test classes can be stripped of their direct inheritance from JUnit.

To do this in TestNG you'll need to annotate your test method with a data provider:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "MyProvider")
public void testSomeStuff() {}
```

and then implement a corresponding provider using either a 2D array (if your test cases are small and already known):

```
@DataProvider(name = "MyProvider")
public Object[][] myDataProvider() {}
```

or by using the following if your test cases are large or unknown:

```
@DataProvider(name = "MyProvider")
public Iterator<Object[]> myDataProvider() {}
```

[This article](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/) may be helpful for understanding the differences between JUnit and TestNG.